# SQL integer type

Tags: mysql, sql, integer, token, sql-types

I'm trying to create this simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE BOOKLENDED
(
LIBRARY_CARD_NUMBER  INTEGER  NOT NULL ,
FOREIGN KEY (LIBRARY_CARD_NUMBER) REFERENCES BORROWER (LIBRARY_CARD_NUMBER),

SEQUENCE INTEGER UNIQUE,

ISBN_NUMBER INT  NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (ISBN_NUMBER) REFERENCES BOOK(ISBN_NUMBER),

LIBRARIAN_ID INTEGER
RETURN_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
CHECKOUT_DATE DATE  NOT NULL
)
```

And I'm having this error:

> 7: Unexpected token: INTEGER in statement [CREATE TABLE BOOKLENDED (
>   LIBRARY_CARD_NUMBER  INTEGER  NOT NULL , FOREIGN KEY
>   (LIBRARY_CARD_NUMBER) REFERENCES BORROWER (LIBRARY_CARD_NUMBER),
>
> SEQUENCE INTEGER]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, to elicit the most optimal response from the community please make sure you're question follows the [mcve]. Recommended Reading: [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to give two constraints(`NOT NULL,FOREIGN KEY`) at a time. instead u can add the `FOREIGN KEY` at the end: Try the follwing

```
CREATE TABLE BOOKLENDED
(
LIBRARY_CARD_NUMBER  INTEGER  NOT NULL ,
SEQUENCE INTEGER,
ISBN_NUMBER INT  NOT NULL,
LIBRARIAN_ID INTEGER,
RETURN_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
CHECKOUT_DATE DATE  NOT NULL,
UNIQUE (SEQUENCE),
FOREIGN KEY (LIBRARY_CARD_NUMBER) REFERENCES BORROWER (LIBRARY_CARD_NUMBER),
FOREIGN KEY (ISBN_NUMBER) REFERENCES BOOK(ISBN_NUMBER)
);
```

Comment: Thank you, your code is working. But I don't understand why I can't give the two constraints at the same time (I'm starting learning Database and SQL)

Comment: Also I got an error here: SEQUENCE INTEGER UNIQUE, because of the unique constraint.

Comment: Can you please post the error u r getting? and feel free to mark it as answer if it helped u to solve ur problem.

Comment: Here it is : 1: Unexpected token: UNIQUE in statement [CREATE TABLE BOOKLENDED
(
LIBRARY_CARD_NUMBER  INTEGER  NOT NULL ,
SEQUENCE INTEGER UNIQUE]

Comment: I don't know why is that not working.anyway Please try my updated answer and let me know if u still have the problem

Comment: Please mark it as a answer if it helped. will help others :)